# Errors in neato.launch file?

Tags: rviz, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm trying to map with xv-11 in rviz. When I type $ roslaunch hector_slam_launch neato.launch; I have this:"lookupTransform base_link to neato_laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame". Are there errors in my launchfile? Thanks.

```
node pkg="xv_11_laser_driver" type="neato_laser_publisher" name="xv_11_node"
param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"
param name="firmware_version" value="2"
param name="frame_id" value="laser"
param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"
param name="map_frame" value="map"
param name="base_frame" value="base_frame"
param name="odom_frame" value="base_frame"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224306/errors-in-neato.launch-file?/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-01-18**:
Looks like ROS can't calculate transformation from base_link to the laser. Could you provide full launch file? Do you launch tf node?

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-01-18**:
This is the launch file
https://github.com/JanezCim/Neato-XV-11-Hector-SLAM/blob/master/neato.launch
How I launch tf node?

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-01-19**:
I try to type "$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher" but I have this answer "static_transform_publisher exited due to not having the right number of arguments"; what is it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for latest comment, see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/224507/error-in-static_transform_publisher/?answer=224511#post-id-224511)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-01-20**:
It works! Thank you so much!